# Android Endless List/Grid using universal image loader

Tags: android, image, list, loader

I am using Universal Image Loader library to load a grid and `ListView` of a bunch of image URLs.

I have a method to pull 24 at a time, and add them to an `ArrayList`.

My adapter basically gets the count from that `ArrayList`, and displays them fine.

In my `getView` method of the adapter, I have a check basically seeing if they are at the max image (the size of the `ArrayList`), and if so, it runs another method to get 24 more.

This actually works GREAT, and loads another 24 images below, but after about 2-3 times, I get an error saying that the data has changed but the context doesn't know.

I tried to use a `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I put it in the adapter right after it runs the method for getting more images...now after 2-3x, I don't get an error, but I can't click any items anymore.

Is there a way to run `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my method OUTSIDE of the adapter?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

MyAdapter here is your costomized adapter class's object.

Take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/antonio081014/Price-and-Tip/blob/master/src/com/antonio081014/pricetip/MainActivity.java).

Comment: i am using:


 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter());
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
startImageGalleryActivity(position);
}
});

listView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(false, true));

itemAdapter doesn't seem to have a notifyDataSetChanged method

Comment: OK, for me, usually I just use customized BaseAdapter, it's more flexible. But it makes me spending more time on getView function.